# Postgresql 13 - Support for partition by reference

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, database-partitioning

We have the following partition set up in Oracle which we need to migrate to Postgresql (version 13)-

```
CREATE TABLE A (
id number(10) not null,
name varchar2(100),
value varchar2(100),
createdat date
constraint a_pk primary key (id))
partition by range (createdat);

CREATE TABLE B (
id number(10) not null,
a_id number(10) not null,
....
....
constraint b_pk primary key (id),
constraint b_a_fk foreign key (a_id) references a (id) on delete cascade
) partition by reference (b_a_fk)
```

Partition by reference is not supported in Postgresql. Could anyone please advise the alternatives to achieve the same in Postgresql. Basically we need to ensure that when older partitions are dropped from both tables, all records in table "B" should get dropped corresponding to related records in "A".

Comment: Not possible. Unfortunately, you still can't have a primary key/foreign key like that on partitioned tables in Postgres (it still doesn't support global indexes that are needed for that)

Comment: Unrelated to your question: why migrate to Postgres 13 today, when Postgres 14 is readily available? (Postgres 14 doesn't support this either, but it has many other improvements)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, we are planning to use azure managed postgresql PaaS option which currently only supports version 13. So the only way to support this scenario in PostgreSQL would be to add a date column in table B such that this new date column will have exactly same value as A.CREATEDAT for all records in B for same parent record in A; then partition B by this new date column. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep a redundant copy of `createdat` in `b` so that you can use it as partitioning key.

To make sure that the related dates are the same, consider the following idea:

- you cannot have `id` as a primary key, since it does not contain the partitioning key `createdat`
- so instead use `(id, createdat)` as primary key of `a`
- then you can define the foreign key on `b` on `(a_id, createdat)`, which will automatically guarantee that the related dates are identical

Sure, that solution is not perfect – in particular, you cannot guarantee uniqueness of `id`. But I think it is the best you can have.

Comment: Does the redundant `createddat` has to be passed with each insert and update statement to all the child tables? If I have around 6 dependent tables, this has to be copied to all the tables

Comment: @ShivangMIttal Yes, you would have to do that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Another less disruptive solution being suggested is to use hash partitioning on foreign key in the child tables. This minimizes changes to be done in both DB and APP since we do not need to create an additional column (createdat) in child tables and populate the same from App; also no one time script to update createdat for existing records. What is your opinion on this approach?

Comment: That won't work. A foreign key always has to reference a primary key or a unique key. Which constraint would you reference from the hash partitioned table? Perhaps I misunderstand, but the way that the child table is partitioned shouldn't have any impact on the question. Or do you mean that you want to use hash partitioning on both the parent and the child table, and the parent table is hash partitioned on the primary key? Sure, that works, but what is the point? That would be an entirely different partitioning strategy and will have entirely different properties.